# regex select sequences that start with specific number

Tags: python, regex

I want to select select all character strings that begin with 0

```
 x= '1,1,1075 1,0,39 2,4,1,22409 0,1,1,755,300 0,1,1,755,50'
```

I have

```
re.findall(r'\b0\S*', x)
```

but this returns

```
 ['0,39', '0,1,1,755,300', '0,1,1,755,50']
```

I want

```
['0,1,1,755,300', '0,1,1,755,50']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\b` matches the boundaries between digits and commas too. The simplest way might be not to use a regex at all:

```
thingies = [thingy for thingy in x.split() if thingy.startswith('0')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the boundary `\b` which will match between the comma and number (between any word `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and non word character), you will want to match on start of string or space like `(^|\s)`.

```
(^|\s)0\S*
```

https://regex101.com/r/Mrzs8a/1

Which will match the start of string or a space preceding the target string. But that will also include the space if present so I would suggest either trimming your matched string or wrapping the latter part with parenthesis to make it a group and then just getting group 1 from the matches like:

```
(?:^|\s)(0\S*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Mrzs8a/2